# How do I check if an icon has transparency before i use it as app icon in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, appicon

I'm at a point of adding app icon in my app, after successfully getting all the screen sizes when I launch my app on a real device my app Icon has a black background on the edges of the icon. Now most forums suggests my icon should be opaque and should have no transparency. So how do I check if the icon has transparency and if so how do I remove them?

Comment: Off-topic. This is not a question about programming. You can use any graphics software (even Apple's Preview) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

for this purpose you need recreate an icon and later when you export this icon verify preferences when you save or export property transparecy, change for white or black. the nex example is in illustrator formatt settings.[image]